# Radio button value set conditionally

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form with an input that asks for a person age, like this: `<input type="number" matInput name="personAge">` and also a radio button that asks is the person is on Medicare:

```
    <p>Are you on Medicare?</p>
    <mat-radio-group 
      name="personIsOnMedicare" 
      [(ngModel)]="model.personIsOnMedicare"> 
      <mat-radio-button
        *ngFor="let ans of answers" 
        [value]="ans.value">
          {{ans.display}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

What I want to achieve is that if the person age is equal or more than `65` the radio button sets automatically to `Yes`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the value for `model.personIsOnMedicare`. Since it is bind with ngModel, it update the radio button selection.

### html

```
<input type="number" matInput #name name="personAge" (change)="updateMedicareStatus(name.value)">
```

### ts

```
updateMedicareStatus(age:number){
  if(age >= 65){
     this.model.personIsOnMedicare = "Yes"; //check this value
  }else{
    this.model.personIsOnMedicare = "No"; //check this value
  }
}
```